# Generics and comparing if two objects are the same?

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing my own generic class but I am confused how you compare two objects when the class only uses generics.

As an example say i have:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_array[i] == item) // cannot use == on T and T
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be valid as i get an error for my if statement saying i cannot use `==` on types T and T.

This makes sense since it could easily be structs passed in, so equality wouldn't make much sense, so how does lists and other generic classes do comparisons like this?

Comment: `_array[i].GetType() == item.GetType()`

Comment: How come that works if the type is a struct in lists for example ? Comparing if they are the same type seems like its only half the issue for structs isn't it ?

Comment: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` which will use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` if applicable, `object.Equals` otherwise. For structs the default `object.Equals` uses reflection to do a field by field compare

Comment: Adding to **pinkfloydx33's** fine comment, you should possibly require that `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` for improved equality

Comment: Why doesn't C#'s list enforce that requirement @MickyD ?

Comment: _"Why doesn't C#'s list enforce that requirement"_ - because it has no `where T ...` constraint.

Comment: I meant why didn't they opt to since you mentioned doing so improves equality?

Comment: [`List<T>` also use `EqualityComparer.Default`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,324)

Comment: @Charlieface so it would use reflection on structs you make if you don't include equality functions ?

Comment: For structs that don't implement `IEquatable<T>`, [it eventually calls through to `Object.Equals`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,250) you can follow the source code on that site